# Capture KeyCode on options of the select list using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dropdown list where there are 3 options:

```
<select>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
```

Now what I want to do is to capture what KEY the user is pressing on the options. And if he presses the Enter key I want to perform submission.

Comment: isn't it's submitted automatically?

Comment: I don't really understand the question. "what KEY the user is pressing on the options" - ???

Comment: no i wont to perform an action which do some calculations and then send the value to the server.

Comment: All i want to know is what KEY the user is pressing when the drop-down list is expanded. And initiate my action only when user presses enter key

Comment: @nicael by options i meant by <option> element.

Comment: I understand that you meant <option>. But they are selected with mouse, aren't they?

Comment: `var input = jQuery("#faq_select option");//faq_select this is the select list
input.on('keyup', function(event){
        var KeyCode = event.keyCode?event.keyCode:event.which;
  
if(window.key ==37||window.key ==38||window.key ==39||window.key ==40||window.key ==9)
{
  console.log("do not send this"+window.key);
  window.key="undefined";

}
else
{
console.log("->"+strContext);
console.log("send"+window.key);
 if (strContext.indexOf(".none") == -1){
  if((strContext.lastIndexOf(".")+1) != strContext.length){
   navcontext = strContext;
   ButtonRequest = 'change_Context';
   botSubmit();
}}}`

Comment: @nicael i am working for a client who also want to make sure that user should be able to do all things using keyboard only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
  $(document).keypress(function(e) {
        if(e.which == 13) {  //If "Enter" Pressed.
           //Submit form 
       }

     });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want detect Enter use

```
$(document).keydown(function(e)
     {
if (e.keyCode == 13) 
      {
   alert("You pressed Enter");
      }
     }
```

Comment: i have used this but it only works till the focus is not on dropdown box but once it is on dropdown list. pressing Enter will expand the list and after that i just can not capture the ENTER key

Comment: hey @Neophyte your code is also doing it but unfortunately i can accept only one answer as the correct one.

Comment: No problem friend. which one you feel like good Accept it. better luck in your project.